# How to commit to db before sidekiq transaction is complete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am trying to update a table row on iteration within the job. Below is the code sample

```
class UpdateTableJob < ApplicationJob

  def perform(arg1, arg2)
    User.each do |person|
      person.update_attributes(:name => "test")
      sleep 25
    end
  end

end
```

Say I have 100 users and only after the iteration of 100 user is done, I could see that change being committed to db. But how can I get that committed on each update?

Comment: 1. Are you really sure `perform` is working in transaction?

Comment: 2. It's wrong way NOT to use transaction as in your example

Comment: In the 2nd comment, are you saying transaction is mandatory. As I said when I try to get the value from database after I update the user, I can't find it updated but only after the job is complete, it gets updated. But when I try to commit db forcefully after that update then I am able to see the change in db.

Comment: Think about exception in the middle of the cycle. Its better to have idempotent job. Another option is to enqueue one job per update.

Answer (score 1):

Create a transaction explicitly so you control the boundaries.

```
class UpdateTableJob < ApplicationJob

  def perform(arg1, arg2)
    User.each do |person|
      User.transaction do
        person.update_attributes(:name => "test")
        sleep 25
      end
    end
  end
end
```